# Average mirror\symmetry of a model

Tags: mirror

I have a raw mesh, obtained  from photogrammetry (see picture).

1. I interested in head. (Neck i can cut off).
2. Open holes and some model defects i can repair by some modelling and sculpting. So, model will be manifold.
3. My friend wants lowpoly model for game industry. (I know retopology etc.)

The problems are:

1. Photogrammetry model does not have "middle (symmetry) point".
2. Model is not exactly symmetrical.

Simple solution

1. Define midpoint of nose tip as center of vertical symmetry.
2. Rotate model around midpoint for approximately vertical symmetry.
3. Cut model via center.
4. Mirror and merge halfs
5. Correct model in sculpting mode (symmetrical mode)

I did it, but resulting model not similar to original (I tried A-half mirror and B-half mirror)

**The questions are:**

1. How to define "most certain" vertical axe of symmetry and rotation of head for defining A-half and B-half.
2. How to modify A-half and B-half by following formula 
   **A-half_new= (0.5xA-half) + (0.5xB-half)** and **B-half_new= (0.5xA-half) + (0.5xB-half)**
   as result **A-half_new = B-half_new** , so i obtain some kind of "average symmetry" for the model.

[image]

below i attached example of "average mirror"

[image]

Comment: what is the need of doing that if the final model is lowpoly?

Comment: First of all i need HiPoly model with "average symmetry". Then i will do lowpoly. Anyway, i need quality HiPoly.

Comment: You can try around this: copy the model, reverse the copy along X (recalculate normals). Then add a shrinkwrap modifier to the original targeting the copy, and apply this modifier as shape key. If this works so far, the average will be the shape key at 0.5.

Comment: I did it, and i think it's VERY close to solution. But i just mirrored the model (not "reverse" and not "recalculate normals"). Model now seems symertical.

Comment: You're right, just mirroring is more simple.